# Space journeying cities to new inhabitable planet, size and society

Tags: society, space-travel, religion

So in this future society (from earth), man decided it worthwhile  to inhabit new far away planets. Sadly, faster than light travel or communication has not been found and cryostasis never worked out. Therefore travelling to other planets means a journey:

- between hundreds or thousands of years.
- spanning tens or hundreds of generations.
- For further away planets communication with earth would take more than a human life.

Society started imagining `space journey worlds`. Space ships that support a society for a journey of possibly many thousands of years.

But the main concern is how to create it in a way that travellers will find themselves at the new planet with reasonable probability:

- How large must a `space journey world` be and what does it look like?
- How should the society be shaped at the inception and during the journey so they have chance?
- What justification is needed to put earth people on a `space journey world`, noting they (and many generations after them) will never set foot on a planet again?

Some notes:

- Earth Society is interested in sending out `worlds` that have some probability of making it, partial failure is acceptable. Failure can come to space hazards or the travellers breaking the ship. Worse case scenario is that they reengineer the ship to go back to earth without reaching the destination (and staying there).
- Potentially many (hundreds?!thousands?!) of `worlds` may be sent out in the course of many generations. Not all planets are inhabitable in the end. Many worlds will be sent, but not all will find a home.
- Earth society is not biased towards what the space society looks like. Transparancy can be employed, but they are not above inventing some religion to increase the chances. But the design of it needs to allow for a life with human dignity. Tying them up platos cave style is a no no.
- There needs to be relative gravity onboard, for example the `world` can travel at a continuous acceleration equal to the earths gravity. This also gives an indication on how long the journey may take precisely.
- Any resource in the solar system is available to create these space journey worlds.

Comment: This is three distinct questions here, and is therefore against the WBSE guidelines. These are pretty much just Generation Ships, though, and Generation Ships are an old staple of sci-fi, so poke around the internet and see if you can find any discussions covering these points elsewhere.

Comment: The usual term for what you call a space journey world is a [generation ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_ship). You will be more lucky in your Googling if you use the accepted phrase. There is a [dedicated entry](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/generation_starships) on the *Encyclopedia of Science Fiction*.